# Change Tumblr hiding my photoset

Tags: hide, tumblr

I want to make my theme show the photoset like it does with normal photos, but one under another.

I'm using this theme right now http://theme-neptune.tumblr.com/

And this is the code for the Photoset block

```
{block:Photoset}

    {block:IndexPage} 
    <div class="photoset">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="hover">
            <a href="{Permalink}" class="set">PHOTOSET</a>
            <a href="{Permalink}">See full set</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      {Photoset-250}
    </div>
    {/block:IndexPage} 

    {block:PermalinkPage} 
    {Photoset-500}
    {/block:PermalinkPage}

    {block:IndexPage}
    {block:ifshowcaption}
    {block:Caption}
    <div class="caption photo_caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
    {/block:ifshowcaption}
    {/block:IndexPage}

{/block:Photoset}
```

Im totally new to all this, I need help.

Comment: Not sure why the down vote. This is one of the rare, first time asking, tumblr question that includes a clear question and relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

**Photoset Photos**

You can loop through the photos in a photoset using `{block:Photos}`:

```
{block:Photoset}
{block:Photos}
<img src="{PhotoURL-250}">
{/block:Photos}
{/block:Photoset}
```

This will output each photo as an `img` element. Below is the markup for the OP's question:

```
{block:Photoset}

    {block:IndexPage} 
    <div class="photoset">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="hover">
            <a href="{Permalink}" class="set">PHOTOSET</a>
            <a href="{Permalink}">See full set</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      {block:Photos}
      <img src="{PhotoURL-250}"{block:Caption} alt="{PlaintextCaption}"{/block:Caption}>
      {/block:Photos}

    </div>
    {/block:IndexPage} 

    {block:PermalinkPage} 
    {block:Photos}
    <img src="{PhotoURL-500}"{block:Caption} alt="{PlaintextCaption}"{/block:Caption}>
    {/block:Photos}
    {/block:PermalinkPage}

    {block:IndexPage}
    {block:ifshowcaption}
    {block:Caption}
    <div class="caption photo_caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
    {/block:ifshowcaption}
    {/block:IndexPage}

{/block:Photoset}
```